# Best Practice Of Unit Test Direct Enum Call

Tags: java, string, unit-testing, enums

Should Enum be called directly when writing unit test?

Here is one option:

```
String expected = "here is not important text" + ObjectState.GOOD_STATE.stringValue();
assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

Here is the second

```
String expected = "here is not important text GOOD_STATE";
assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

First option easily maintainable code however second is human readable code when things become complicated.

So Which one is better. Is there any best practice?

Comment: Why do you want to check for the `"here is not important text"`? What do you want to check? The `stringValue()` of `GOOD_STATE`, or that the `ObjectState` you got is `GOOD_STATE`?

Comment: you can add the comment in the asserEquals (comment,expcted,actual)

Comment: Does this question boil down to "is readability more important than maintainability when things become complicated?"  That's how I'm interpreting it, and as such it's not strictly answerable.

Answer (score -1):

If the leading part of the text is unimportant, then you should test just the important part:

```
assertTrue(actual.endsWith(ObjectState.GOOD_STATE.stringValue()));
```

Or just

```
assertTrue(actual.contains(ObjectState.GOOD_STATE.stringValue()));
```